# py2exe with Pypy

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, pypy

I have been developing a python script called script.py . I wish to compile it using py2exe. However, I wish to make sure the the final script.exe is optimized with the pypy JIT compiler and hence faster.

P.S. I am new to both py2exe and pypy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

py2exe and pypy are incompatible. It's possible to write an equivalent of py2exe for pypy, but some work has to be done.